# Sub-menu items causing main menu items to spread out on hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, flexbox

I have this unordered list I've styled into a menu. I want the blue menu items to be centered underneath the top level red menu items, so I've given the red menu items a display of flex:

```
nav > ul > li > a {
  color: red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

The problem is when the red menu items are hovered over the blue menu items push the other red menu items out of the way.

https://jsfiddle.net/m14dxtz8/

Any ideas how to fix this without JS?

Comment: haven't had a chance to get to it, but a relative position should do it. Give me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
ul ul {position: absolute;}
```

By making their positions absolute, you take them out of the document flow so they don't "push things around."

Comment: Unfortunately this overrides their centering under the top level menu items.